# make Attribute, which describes AccessLevel of model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-attributes

So... I have this simple model called `Employee`:

```
public class Employee {

    public int WorkerID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to "decorate" all properties with `AccessLevel` like this:

```
[AccessLevel(1)]
public class Employee {
    [AccessLevel(1)]
    public int WorkerID { get; set; }

    [AccessLevel(1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [AccessLevel(1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [AccessLevel(2)]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I've read about [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), but still don't know how to create right one and somehow access it like

```
 Employee.Salary.GetAccessLevel();
```

How can I make that kind of **Attribute**? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need this when an other user (not allowed to see salary) wants to access data of an Employee, but you don't want to show the Salary?

Comment: The subsequent link on the page you referenced discusses [Custom Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)

Comment: That's one of example.  If `User` has `AccessLevel` 1, he can see only properties with 1 or lower.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks. I've read this. But did't saw any example of accessing this data.

Comment: I think that you are approaching this wrong. C# classes already have `access modifiers` and class hierarchies. I think that you are trying to replicate something that already exists.

Comment: Anyway, if you really wanted to, you could use `reflection` to look for the value. Personally, I feel that if you need to do this then it should be part of the model, not an attribute - a decorator.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this

Comment: I think a better solution would be using DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) which contain the necessary data, the requester is able to see

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin I will. But I need to use DTO depends of AccessLEvel

Comment: @Morasiu Yes sure, then make DTOs depending on AccessLevel like `DTOEmployeeForAdministrator` and `DTOEmployeeForEmployee`. Each holding a subset of the Properties of the Non-DTO class

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin That's my concept. I've already in love with AutoMapper :)

Comment: @Morasiu Then I don't see the problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `reflection` get property attribute by `GetCustomAttribute` method and use linq to check the auth value.

```
typeof(Employee)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x=>x.GetCustomAttribute<AccessLevel>().val > 1) // here can write your logic.
        .Select(x => x.Name);
```